# How to reduce memory consumption and processing time of Python's itertools.product?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, simulation, python-itertools

#### What I Have

I have created a function to generate all possible matrices for a given number of rows and columns and a given list of possible values.

```
def generate_matrices(rows, columns, values):
    """Returns an iterable over all possible matrices for a given
       number of rows and columns and a given list of possible
       values.

       Arguments:
           rows    -- number of rows desired for each matrix
           columns -- number of columns desired for each matrix
           values  -- list of values desired for iteration

       Returns:
           returns an iterator over the generated matrices

       Dependencies:
           requires the itertools library (`import itertools`)
    """

    x = itertools.product(values, repeat = columns)
    y = itertools.product(x, repeat = rows)

    return y
```

#### What I Need

This works fine for small inputs (small numbers of rows and columns, few values), but for larger inputs, all system memory is consumed in the processing of the function.

**How can I minimize the memory consumption and processing time of this function?**

*The purpose of these matrices is to provide test values to a set of functions to maximize the output of a particular formula. If there is a better way to test all possible inputs for a variable number of variables and variable ranges, please advise.*

Comment: Do you really need to test *all possible matrices on the planet*? Why don't you use [hypothesis testing](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/numpy.html) and let the framework do its magic (like automatically narrowing down what matrices and what values break the test)?

Comment: What's too large, a list of all `y` or just one iteration.  I don't have a feeling for what putting `x` in `y` does.

Comment: `itertools.product` creates an iterator, not a list. If you iterate all elements one by one, it shouldn't consume a lot of memory. Did you convert the iterator to a list or did something similar?

Comment: @Dabiuteef The problem is that the second `itertools.product` needs to run the result of the first one to start producing elements.

Comment: @NilsWerner You're quite right - I was approaching the problem from the wrong perspective. Instead of testing all matrices that exist, I'll test only those matrices that are possible given the constraints of the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a "lazy" matrix generator, for example like this:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

def generate_matrices(rows, columns, values, dtype=None):
    dtype = dtype or float
    for mat in generate_matrices_rec(rows, columns, values, np.empty((rows, columns), dtype)):
        yield mat.copy()

def generate_matrices_rec(rows, columns, values, mat):
    if rows <= 0:
        yield mat
    else:
        for row in product(values, repeat=columns):
            mat[0] = row
            for submat in generate_matrices_rec(rows - 1, columns, values, mat[1:]):
                yield mat
```

Then you could iterate through the matrices like:

```
for matrix in generate_matrices(rows, columns, values):
    # Do something with the matrix...
```

This should not consume your memory (unless you try to store all the generate matrices in a list or something similar, of course). However, the number of possible matrices can grow astronomically large very quickly (in particular the number is `len(values) ** (rows * columns)`), so even if you do not run out of memory you will easily run out of time.

Comment: Btw I wrote the generator for NumPy matrices because I assume that's what you are using (from the tags), but it is just as feasible to write a similar function that produces lists of lists.

Comment: NumPy matrices are perfect. Thank you for your solution - it works well and solves the memory issue, though, as you noted, the time problem isn't really surmountable here.

Answer (score 0):

It was little hard to picture what was happening just from reading your code.  So here's a small example (something which you should have done for us - if you really want help!):

```
In [201]: x=itertools.product([1,2],repeat=2)
In [202]: list(x)
Out[202]: [(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
In [203]: y=itertools.product(Out[202],repeat=2)
In [204]: list(y)
Out[204]: 
[((1, 1), (1, 1)),
 ((1, 1), (1, 2)),
 ((1, 1), (2, 1)),
 ((1, 1), (2, 2)),
 ((1, 2), (1, 1)),
 ((1, 2), (1, 2)),
 ((1, 2), (2, 1)),
 ((1, 2), (2, 2)),
 ((2, 1), (1, 1)),
 ((2, 1), (1, 2)),
 ((2, 1), (2, 1)),
 ((2, 1), (2, 2)),
 ((2, 2), (1, 1)),
 ((2, 2), (1, 2)),
 ((2, 2), (2, 1)),
 ((2, 2), (2, 2))]
```

So even if you consume `y` iteratively, it still has to create the full list of `x` possibilities.

If I read your problem right, you want to test, sequentially, arrays made from elements of `y`, e.g.:

```
In [205]: np.array(Out[204][5])
Out[205]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]])
```

For a larger example:

```
In [206]: x=itertools.product([1,2,3,4],repeat=4)
In [207]: y=itertools.product(x,repeat=3)

In [209]: next(y) 
Out[209]: ((1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1)) 
In [210]: np.array(_) 
Out[210]: array([[1, 1, 1, 1], 
                 [1, 1, 1, 1], 
                 [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

And subsequent `next(y)` will produce more (3,4) arrays, gradually replacing the 1's with values from [1,2,3,4].

How about generating all matrix values with one product:

```
In [214]: z = itertools.product([1,2,3,4],repeat=12)
In [215]: np.array(next(z)).reshape(3,4)
Out[215]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

As far as I can tell it produces the same arrays as your nested generators.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll be sure to include examples next time I post a question.